# The url upload->data() returns is inaccessible

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, upload

when I use the CodeIgniter to upload pic to server , pictures are stored in '/controllors/file', and i have changed the file directory's permission to 777 already.But when i try to visit the url, "https://server/file/xxx.png" ,it returns 404. The url is correct, what's wrong with server ,please? My English is poor

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store a picture, then save the file in a directory that is outside the codeigniter standard paths - .htaccess could be getting in the way.  I suggest you have a structure like assets/images and store the images there.

Controllers are to serve files that require some sort of business logic - so does the user have access to the image etc?

Also look at the owner of the folder - it probably should have permissions of 755